# Outputing only those rows which matches keyword

Tags: regex, string, file, search, keyword

I'm trying output only those in table rows which matches keyword, but does not work. I am trying use strpos, substr and other functions.  My code looks like this. Has someone idea, how to fix it and adapt that function correctly?

```
 <?php

    $start_date = strtotime($_POST['start']);
    $end_date = strtotime($_POST['end']);

    settype($start_date, "integ`enter code here`er");  
    settype($end_date, "integer");

    $total = 0;


        if (isset($_POST["start"]) && !empty($_POST["end"])) {

            $files = glob('arch/*.log.*');   

>scan files



foreach($files as $failas)
            {   
                $file_mod_time = filemtime($failas);

                            if (($start_date<$file_mod_time) && ($end_date>$file_mod_time)) //looking for specific date
                        {   

                $file = @fopen($failas, "r") or die("Cannot open file!\n");  
                while ($filePart = fread($file, 4146)) { 
                    preg_match_all('/(?>--\w{8}-A--).*?(?=(--\w{8}-A--)|\Z)/s', $filePart, $blockMatch, PREG_SET_ORDER);  


                    foreach ($blockMatch as $singleBlockMatch) {
                        if (isset($singleBlockMatch[0])) {
                            preg_match_all('/.*?--\w{8}-A--\n(.*?)\s\w*?\s(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).*?POST (\S*?) HTTP.*?--\w{8}-C--\s(.*?\s)/s', $singleBlockMatch[0], $match, PREG_SET_ORDER); // reads a blocks


                             /* var_dump($match); */    
                            /* if (strpos($singleBlockMatch[0],$_POST['search'])===($match)) {*/ 
                            foreach ($match as $pos) {


                        $search = $_POST['search'];         
                        $pos = strpos($singleBlockMatch[0], $search);             //tries take specific rows, matching keyword

                        $wert = substr($singleBlockMatch[0],$pos);  
                            }   ?>  
                                 <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $total++; ?></td>
                    <td> <?php echo $wert[1]; ?></td>
                    <td> <?php echo $wert[2]; ?></td>
                    <td> <?php echo $wert[3]; ?></td>
                    <td> <?php echo $wert[4]; ?></td>
                    <?php                                  



        }
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
            }
        else {
                    echo "Fill a fields";
                }   
     ?>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dlzQ.png)

Comment: please give an example of input and expected output

Comment: Could you elaborate what regular expression does not work as expected and give a sample input string and if it should match or not. Otherwise, it is unlikely you'll getting help here.

Comment: Right now it outputs all content and regex is correct, but I prefer on content which has specific keyword from search field

Comment: And code does not work in lines where is strpos functions